# set pcl text to red

Tags: printing, printer

Given the windows PCL separator page with escape character '\' (without quotes), how would i set an arbitrary line to red, and then the next line back to black?

heres the file so far:

\
\H1B\L%-12345x@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=PCL
\U\L
\H1B\L&l1T\0
\M\B\S\N\U
\U\LJob : \I
\U\LDate: \D
\U\LTime: \T
\U\L
\U\L  Please be sure to take only your documents
\U\L
\E

ive been asked to make the please be sure part red

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `\H` command, for example, to initiate a hex character value (such as `1B` for `Esc`) along with a sequence of characters that would be specific to a particular printer and its control language. Without knowing which printer you're targeting, that's the most I can offer.

Here's a PDF file that may be useful if you have an HP color printer:
[HP PCL/PJL Reference (PCL 5 Color) - Technical Reference Manual (bpl13212)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/bpl13212/bpl13212.pdf)

Here's an example:

```
\H1B\L*r3U \H1B*v1S This is some red text\H1B\L*v0S \H1BE
```

Comment: its a lexmark c782 - i tried this and just got a blank line

Comment: @ANervousTwitch: Are you running the printer in PCL mode or Postscript mode? If you have just a line of simple text, does that get printed?

Comment: im trying to customize the PCL separator page that comes with windows.  i believe its in PCL mode.

other lines of simple text print fine, and if i remove the color commands from this particular line, it reappears.

Comment: @ANervousTwitch: Are you modifying `c:\windows\system32\pcl.sep`? That's what I'd recommend that you do. Please add the current contents of your `.sep` file to your question above.

Comment: thats what i was doing.  contents have been added.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try.  Should work on any PCL printer.

```
\E\*r#U\&p#1yourtexthere\&p#0
```

Comment: its a lexmark c782 - i tried this and just got a blank line